# Why does not the perfect number formula imply there are infinitely many perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

We know the even perfect number formula is $2^{p-1}(2^p  − 1)$ and it is known that the multiplication of a even number and odd number is a even number. So why can't we say there are infinitely many perfect numbers since $2^p-1$   has to be a prime number in $2^{p-1}(2^p  − 1)$ and it is known that there are infinitely many prime numbers?

Note: I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: With regards to the infinitude of Mersenne primes: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/89563/137524

Answer (score 3):

Because $2^{p}-1$ is **not** always a prime.  When it is a prime, it is called a [Mersenne prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime).

For example, $11$ is prime, but $2^{11}-1 = 2047 = 23 \times 89$.

Comment: Ohh, I understood it now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If $2^p - 1$ is a prime (often called a Mersenne prime), then $2^{p-1}(2^p - 1)$ is a perfect number. While there are infinitely many primes, it is not known whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes. There are many primes which cannot be written in the form $2^p - 1$, for example, the prime $5$.

Comment: I was doing a research and I saw the question "Are there infinitely many perfect numbers?" in the list of unsolved problems in mathematics(link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) Should I assume this question was already solved?

Comment: It is still unsolved. I did not claim it is true or false, I just pointed out that while there are infinitely many primes, it is unknown whether there are infinitely many primes of the form $2^p - 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)